# React-Native expo debug errors not showing any useful info or error message

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

I'm a react-native newbie and I'm using expo to build my maps, one issue I have is when I communicate with my backend (localhost) via axios and something goes wrong in the backend I get a pretty generic error message, only useful thing here is the status error code 500.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYGAq.png

Take a look, even though I'm wrapping async/await in try/catch block I get no error message or error line, this makes debugging a hell, is developing with expo/react always like this?

Comment: Looks like your exception handling is not configured correctly. Can you add the code block you use to send the request ?

Comment: that's an ```axios``` error response. You need to configure your backend to return the respone you want.

Comment: My backend is laravel, it should automatically return any error afaik

Comment: Still this has nothing to do with RN or expo, it is axios. Can you also post the code, we don't know how you are trying to access the error messages.

Comment: Uhm, that's all the code related to my axios call, you mean I should maybe use axios interceptor to correctly print errors?

Comment: there's no code in your post